# How to specify metadata for dask.dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask

The docs provide good examples, [how metadata can be provided](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-design.html#metadata). However I still feel unsure, when it comes to picking the right dtypes for my dataframe.

- Could I do something like `meta={'x': int 'y': float,
  'z': float}` instead of `meta={'x': 'i8', 'y': 'f8', 'z': 'f8'}`?
- Could somebody hint me to a list of possible values like 'i8'?  What
  dtypes exist?
- How    can I specify a column, that contains arbitrary objects? How can I    specify a column, that contains only instances of one class?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The available basic data types are the ones which are offered through numpy. Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.types.html) for a list.

Not included in this set are datetime-formats (e.g. `datetime64`), for which additional information can be found in the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html) and [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html) documentation.

The meta-argument for dask dataframes usually expects an empty pandas dataframe holding definitions for columns, indices and dtypes.

One way to construct such a DataFrame is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
meta = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
meta.a = meta.a.astype(np.int64)
meta.b = meta.b.astype(np.datetime64)
```

There is also a way to provide a dtype to the constructor of the pandas dataframe, however, I am not sure how to provide them for individual columns each. As you can see, it is possible to provide not only the "name" for datatypes, but also the actual numpy dtype.

Regarding your last question, the datatype you are looking for is "object". For example:

```
import pandas as pd

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.bar = foo

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[Foo(1), Foo(2)], columns=['a'], dtype='object')
df.a
# 0    <__main__.Foo object at 0x00000000058AC550>
# 1    <__main__.Foo object at 0x00000000058AC358>
```

Comment: how can one determine that one of the column of returning dataFrame is `list`, or `dict`?

Answer (score 5):

Both Dask.dataframe and Pandas use NumPy dtypes.  In particular, anything within that you can pass to [np.dtype](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html).  This includes the following:

1. NumPy dtype objects, like `np.float64`
2. Python type objects, like `float`
3. NumPy dtype strings, like `'f8'`

Here is a more extensive list taken from the NumPy docs: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#specifying-and-constructing-data-types

Comment: If the original csv used `converters` to acquire richer types like `list`, then should the meta in dask specify `list` or just `object`?

Comment: Whatever the Pandas datatype would be.  In this case I think Pandas would use an object dtype, but you can try for yourself to see.

Comment: I tried `dask.read_csv` with converters to rich objects and it just worked. The dtypes ended up being objects. But I think the rich objects can also be used in the meta. But I'm not sure its needed. Seems like meta can just be `object`…